# html, body, and div set at 100% width but it's still not taking the full 100%

Tags: html, css, width

I reset the margins and padding to `0`. I set the `<html>`, `<body>` width to 100%.

My CSS looks something like this:

```
html, body { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

Whenever I resize the browser to the point I get a horizontal scroll bar the div doesn't take the full 100% width. Not even the body or html. I have firebugged it and there's about a 180px gap.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

You can use overflow for that

```
html, body { 
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow: auto;
}
```

I also faced similar issue and i used this

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer :**

- Your browser shortcut (Chrome = `Ctrl + Shift + I`, Firefox = `Ctrl + Shift + C`)
- Put your mouse over the gap and follow it all the way down to find the element causing the problem
- Fix it

**Longer answer :**

As Dan Kanze said, if there is a consistent gap then that means some element(s) inside of your wrapper is causing an offset.

To help you further, I suggest you to use one nice devtools that you can find on both Chrome [Chrome devtools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqM27.jpg) & FF [FF devtools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyiQT.jpg).

Shortcuts:
Chrome = `Ctrl + Shift + I`
Firefox = `Ctrl + Shift + C`

Once you're using this, you just have to put your cursor pointer over the gap, and just hover it all over the vertical gap until it finds something, then click and you'll find the bad html guy !

Answer (score 1):

If there is a consistent 180px gap then that means elements inside of your wrapper are causing an offset.

Your container elements look fine.

To find the culprite FF has a great debug tool for exactly this called 3D mode. This will show you outlier from your main container where you can select and find the element in your code.

With a link I can help you further.

Comment: I'll second this. Don't forget that IE adds margin or padding (or both?) to the final width value. I've been bitten by that before. What's your doctype, J.S?

Comment: The elements inside my wrapper are just 2 columns.

Comment: Say something like #lcol {width:40%;} rcol{ width:60%;} and are floating left but I also cleared the float... hm

Comment: without link or your entire source it will be impossible to help you further by anyone here

Comment: doctype is: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Comment: I think the problem lies with what Dan said... in the container elements. I feel I'm very close to solving it. I need to double check all the code from the previous front-end. There's floats that aren't being cleared.

Comment: if you use Firefox... hit CNTRL+SHIFT+I --> 3D Mode.  This should help you imensly.

Comment: There are elements that are position absolute and are images... I don't think this problem will be solvable without the use of javascript to make this a true responsive design. Thank you for all who helped. At-least the markup was improved!